# Allows anonymous request with keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I develop a springboot application, and I use Keycloak as an authorization server thanks to the enforcer policies.
My application.properties be like

```
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[0].path=/api/v1/*
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[0].methods[0].method=*
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[0].claimInformationPointConfig.claims[some-claim]={request.parameter['parameter-a']}
```

I would like to make certain resources accessible by anonymous requests, for example that the route localhost:8080/images/flower.jpg be accessible from a browser without being authenticated.
i tried this

```
   keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name=static-resources 
   keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/images/*
```

but it doesn’t work

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Comment: yes @dreamcash i still need help

Comment: I have a similar setup at home, I tried it out and posted here

Comment: done! I thought I did it last time sorry

Comment: Thanks, not problem, I will shared my configuration with you so that you can applied in your case